# How to output queries in database as strings in OCaml

Tags: sqlite, ocaml

Whenever I output queries in OCaml using [sqlite3-ocaml library](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/sqlite3/), it prints out the information in the database as unit rather than strings. I am wondering how I could output the information in the database as strings? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows what you're currently doing to print values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the `cb` function, which is a callback to the [exec](https://mmottl.github.io/sqlite3-ocaml/api/sqlite3/Sqlite3/index.html#val-exec) family of functions. In `exec`, it has type `row -> headers -> unit`, which means that for each call the library will call the callback and provide the row information and the headers information, i.e., it will be called like this `my_callback row hdrs`. It shall return the value of type `unit`, which the OCaml way of saying that it shall not return anything (or anything that it returns will be ignored).

A simple way to print all rows (let's ignore empty values and the header for starters) is to use [exec_not_null_no_headers](https://mmottl.github.io/sqlite3-ocaml/api/sqlite3/Sqlite3/index.html#val-exec_not_null_no_headers), e.g.,

```
let print_query db query = 
  Sqlite3.exec_not_null_no_headers db querty ~cb:(fun row -> 
   Array.iter (fun row -> print_string (row ^ " ")) row;
   print_char '\n')
```

This will print the result of the query to the standard output. If you want, instead of printing the output, collect it into a string,  then you may use the [Buffer](https://ocaml.org/api/Buffer.html) module to build it, e.g.,

```
let query_to_string db query = 
  let buf = Buffer.create 64 in
  Sqlite3.exec_not_null_no_header db query ~cb:(fun row -> 
    Array.iter (fun elt -> 
      Buffer.add_string buf elt;
      Buffer.add_char buf ' ');
    Buffer.add_char buf '\n');
  Buffer.contents buf
```